# How to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin}=\prod'\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, adeles

I want to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin}=\prod_{p\ \mathrm{finite\ places}}'\mathbb{Q}_p$. $\prod_{p\ \mathrm{finite\ places}}'\mathbb{Q}_p$ means for elements $(x_p) \in \mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin},\ x_p \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and for all but finitely $p$, $x_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

I can show that $\forall (x_p) \in \mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin},\ \forall \epsilon_p>0$ and $\epsilon_p=1$ for all but finitely $p$, $\exists\ x \in \mathbb{Q}\ s.t.\ |x-x_p|<\epsilon_p$. The difficulty is how to prove without the condition "$\epsilon_p=1$ for all but finitely $p$". Since the primes are infinite, the chinese reminder theorem doesn't work and I got stuck.

Furthermore, it seems that you can remove any place instead of the infinite place in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}=\prod_{p\ places}'\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the result still holds. How to prove that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $\Bbb{A}_Q = \Bbb{Q} \widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$ (not direct product just that any finite adele is the product of a rational and a profinite integer) where $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}}=\prod_p \Bbb{Z}_p$. Then check that $\Bbb{Z}$ is dense in $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$.

Comment: I can only prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ dense in $\prod_p\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ which has finitely $p_i$. How to prove the infinite?

Comment: Check again the definition of the topology on the adeles and the (restricted) product topology. If $\prod_p a_p \in \prod_p \Bbb{Z}_p$ and $b_n\in \Bbb{Z}, \forall p\le n, b_n\equiv a_p\bmod p^n$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} b=\prod_p a_p $ in $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$.